# Issue with spark-shell command: java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient

Tags: apache-spark, centos7, mapr

I have some issues when a executing spark-shell command:

```
[mapr@node1 ~]$ /opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/bin/spark-shell --master local[2]
```

Error:

```
20/05/02 14:21:34 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:643)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:696)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getMapRFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1405)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1080)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:531)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRClientImpl.<init>(MapRClientImpl.java:136)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:637)
    ... 58 more
java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient
  at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:643)
  at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:696)
  at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getMapRFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1405)
  at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1080)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:93)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:531)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2313)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:95)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient
  at com.mapr.fs.MapRClientImpl.<init>(MapRClientImpl.java:136)
  at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:637)
  ... 58 more
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-mapr-1710
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_242)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> 2020-05-02 14:21:27,8616 ERROR Cidcache fs/client/fileclient/cc/cidcache.cc:2470 Thread: 30539 MoveToNextCldb: No CLDB entries, cannot run, sleeping 5 seconds!
2020-05-02 14:21:32,9268 ERROR Client fs/client/fileclient/cc/client.cc:1329 Thread: 30539 Failed to initialize client for cluster MyCluster, error Connection reset by peer(104)
```

I use Spark-2.1.0 and a cluster MapR with 3 nodes.

I also have the following conf files:
Slaves with a list of nodes:

```
# A Spark Worker will be started on each of the machines listed below.
node2
node3
```

Also add these following lines to `$Spark_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=node1
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=172.17.0.2
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```

Please did any one had the same issue or know how to fix it.

Comment: doesn't solve your issue, but with `--master local[2]` you would never use your cluster. IF it's Spark standalone you have to use `spark:IP_ADDRESS:PORT` and if it is on YARN, you have to use `--master yarn`

Comment: but spark:ID_ADDRESS:PORT is used when we want to start the slaves with the command " $ SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slaves.sh

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you use `--master local[2]` it will never run on the cluster, but only locally and only one the master will be used

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is   ***typical installation issue.*** From Mapr forums I found, Please have a look at  [spark-on-yarn-errors-](https://mapr.com/community/s/question/0D50L00006BIvqVSAT/spark-on-yarn-errors-) they proposed to install commands in the link as well as run configure.sh

Gist of this is ([source mapr forums](https://mapr.com/community/s/question/0D50L00006BIvqVSAT/spark-on-yarn-errors-))...Here is the solution:

```
  -pip uninstall toree

  -pip install --pre toree

  -jupyter toree install --interpreters=Scala,PySparK,SparK,SQL --spark_home=$SPARK_HOME
```

Also, Spark docs says for spark 2.1.0 compatible version is scala 2.11.8

[Spark runs on Java 7+, Python 2.6+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.1.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/)

Hope you have not missed these versions.